# change flag in menu bar to Indian flag

Tags: menu-bar

For India they have Hindi language but it does not have an Indian flag on it. Is there any way to add custom flag images in menu bar?

even if its a hackish way to do it. I am ready for it. I just want to have Indian flag in menu bar.

Comment: I am thinking about creating my own menu app just to have Indian flag in Menu bar

Answer (score 2):

You **can** actually customize your own input source icons via keyboard layouts! I found step-by-step instructions, which involve a bit of graphics editing, a Unicode Keyboard Layout Editor, and some work in Terminal.app: *Salvatore Testa:* [Customizing Your Mac Input Source Icon](http://saltesta.com/hack/customizing-mac-input-source-icon/). Have fun!